# Share state between VSIX Editor Language Extension components

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I've created `Classifier`, `ErrorTagger`, `SignatureHelp` and `TextCompletion` classes. There are all created by providers which are MEF componenents which VS discovers.

The question is, I would like to share a C# object between these components to share state and to allow me to save reparsing the same text from each component. How can I do this? I need this state to be per file being edited.

VS discovers the providers and creates my components using them. But, how can I pass in or share state between them? I did use a global singleton, but when I've got multiple files being edited in VS, they all share the same singleton, but I need a different instance for each file being edited.

Comment: `IServiceProvider` should do the trick. But given everything runs in the same appdomain with newer VS, a static variable should just work too...

Answer (score 1):

One common approach is `ITextView` and `ITextBuffer` both have a Properties property which you can use as a generic bag to put things in. There's even a GetOrCreateSignletonProperty helper on it. It's common to have some sort of component that watches an `ITextBuffer` for changes and does parsing that way, and each other component just grabs this per-text-buffer object.

Classifiers and taggers can also implement `IDisposable`, and `ITextViews` have a close event, so it's also possible to just have a static dictionary somewhere from `ITextBuffer`/`ITextView` to your own type and manage lifetime that way.

Either way you do it -- test! It's very easy to accidentally screw up and leak the `ITextBuffer` or `ITextView`.